# Determining analytically the number of times a line intersects a general 3D surface

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, 3d, surfaces, solid-geometry

Consider a general surface and a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Given equations for both the surface and line, is there a way to analytically determine the **number** of times the line intersects the surface?

I am only interested in the number of intersections, *not* the precise locations of intersection. I know that there are methods to calculate this numerically by first finding where the intersections are, but I want to know if there is a simple method to just calculate the number of intersections.

The surface might be given implicitly as $F(x, y, z)=0$ or parametrically as $\vec{r}(u, v)=x(u, v) \hat{\imath}+y(u, v)\hat{\jmath}+z(u, v)\hat{k}$, and may or may not be closed. The line might be given as $\vec{r}(t)=\vec{r}_0+t \vec{d}$ where the line passes through the point $\vec{r}_0$ and $\vec{d}$ is the direction vector. The line extends infinitely in both directions, but I can also work with the case in which the line has finite endpoints.

EDIT: As pointed out in comments below, I am specifically working with the surface given by an implicit equation of the form

$$
F(x, y, z)=x^k+y^k+z^k-1
$$

where the terms involving $x$, $y$, and $z$ can have constant coefficients. Specifically, I am interested in the region $x$, $y \geq 0$. $k$ can be a general rational exponent greater than $2$. One solution suggested below involving the Sturm sequence works simply enough for integer $k$, where one can write a polynomial involving just the parametric variable by substituting in the equation of the line.

This surface is part of a shape called a superellipsoid, but just taken for $x$, $y \geq 0$ to simplify $F(x, y, z)$. In my application, I can make some geometric and symmetry arguments so that I can only consider this portion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substituting a parametrization of the line into an implicit equation for the surface, the problem becomes one of counting the number of zeros of a function.  If the function is rational, you can do this using Sturm's theorem.  For more general classes of functions, the problem can be unsolvable: see [Richardson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson%27s_theorem).  For example, Laczkovich showed there is no algorithm that, given a function $A(x)$ in the ring generated by integers, $x$, $\sin(x^n)$ and $\sin(\sin(x^n))$, decides whether there is a real solution of $A(x)=0$.

EDIT: If your function involves fractional exponents, it should still be possible to convert the equation to one involving a polynomial.  For example, consider the equation
$$ \sqrt{x^2+1} - (x^4+1)^{1/4} - x + 2 = 0 $$
Write this as $f(\alpha,\beta,x) = \alpha - \beta - x + 2 = 0$
where $\alpha^2 - (x^2+1) = 0$ and $\beta^4 - (x^4+1) = 0$.
First take the resultant of $f(\alpha,\beta,x)$ and $\alpha^2 - (x^2+1)$ with respect to $\alpha$, then the resultant of that and
$\beta^4 - (x^4+1)$ with respect to $\beta$, and we get the
polynomial $-15 x^8 + 64 x^7 - 112 x^6 + 112 x^5 + 160 x^4 - 704 x^3 + 752 x^2 - 320 x$.  Sturm tells us this has four real roots.
However, we must then look at each root (approximately) to check whether the corresponding $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the correct (i.e. positive) square root of $x^2+1$ and fourth root of $x^4+1$:
it turns out that only one of the four roots works.

Comment: That is quite a nice solution. Unfortunately, the specific equation I am working with has fractional exponents so I think that it cannot be posed in terms of a polynomial (maybe a transformation will work??). Do you know if there are ways to extend this method to more complicated functions? Or does such a solution not exist?

Comment: @llorente : Do you have a finite list of rational exponents, or is the set of all rational exponents permissible?

Comment: @EricTowers : It is the set of all rational exponents but all of them must be greater than 2. To be clear, my function looks like $F(x, y, z)=x^k+y^k+z^k+c$ where $k>2$ is the rational exponent and $c$ is some arbitrary constant. Then when you substitute in an equation for a line you get a univariate function.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with resultants. What is the relationship between resultants and the number of roots? Can I think of using resultants as a method to obtain a polynomial expression for Sturm's theorem that preserves the number of roots (but depends on some conditions like in the example)?

Comment: The [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant)  of two polynomials is a polynomial expression of their coefficients, which is equal to zero if and only if the polynomials have a common root.

Comment: @llorente : You seem to have *vastly* more information about $F$ than you shared in the Question.  You should edit this information into your Question as this clarification vastly decreases the range of techniques applicable to your problem.

Comment: @EricTowers : Yes, I have just updated the question with specific details. I had been hoping there were general methods that would not depend greatly on the form of $F$, but clearly this assumption turned out to be false.